# NSPredicate filter using an instance counter on array level

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, instance

In my iOS app, I pull in JSON, and set it to an array. The array looks like this:

```
links =         {

            "link_1" =             {

                clicks = 1;

                ip = "10.0.0.0";

                shorturl = "http://on.example.com/abc";

                timestamp = "2013-10-30 05:56:51";

                title = Example Website;

                url = "http://example.com/page/1/path/";

            };

            "link_2" =             {

                clicks = 10;

                ip = "10.0.0.0";

                shorturl = "http://on.example.com/def";

                timestamp = "2013-10-16 16:55:47";

                title = "Fitbit Force Is the Smartest Fitness Tracker Yet [REVIEW]";

                url = "http://mashable.com/2013/10/16/fitbit-force-review/";

            };
```

I have the following method set up to filter `UITableView` results:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"links.link_1.title contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [filterArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}
```

I need to update the `predicateWithFormat` filter to account for `link_1`, `link_2`, `link_3`, `...`

**QUESTION**: How can I have the filter match any "level" of my array, where the string after `link_` is always a positive number, but can be an infinite number of digits?

I basically need to search the array on the `link_` level, for every positive number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an array, `links` is a dictionary. So just filter `links.allValues` with predicate with format `@"title contains[cd] %@"`.

==Edit==

If I have understood you right, you need filtered link objects:

```
NSArray *linksArray = [[filterArray[0] objectForKey:@"links"] allValues];
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"title contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSArray *filteredLinks = [linksArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Then form `searchResults` in the form you need it, maybe just pass `filteredLinks` as a result.

Comment: Where does `.allValues` come from? Can you please give me an example using my code so I understand your answer? - Thanks!

Comment: @adamdehaven allValues is a NSDictionary's method. links is a NSDictionary object, so you should just get all it's values and filter them. To give you example I need some answers. What is a filterArray variable in your code, how it is gotten? How it's related to the printed links object?

Comment: The `links` object (in my original question) is actually the `NSLog` of the `NSArray *filterArray`. `filterArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]];`

Comment: @adamdehaven Is it really an array? Can it contain several objects like "links" that is printed, each with a pack of "link1", "link2", etc objects inside — like @[ { "link1" : {...}, "link2" : {...}, ... }, { "link1" : {...}, "link2" : {...}, ... }, ...]?

Comment: It is a JSON response that I then put into an array via my last comment. See here: http://pastebin.com/0BZy4qMp

Comment: @adamdehaven pls see edit, maybe it's more clear now

Comment: Ok I "think" that's working... let I just need to try to figure out how to then assign labels...

Comment: How do I then pull in the title, shortURL, and clicks into labels from that?? :) THANKS

Comment: @adamdehaven just [filteredLinks[indexOfNeededLink] objectForKey:@"shorturl"] to get shortURL string for link at indexOfNeededLink index